# Angular ui-grid editDropdownOptionsArray depending on current row

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I want to have a different dropdown array for each row of my ui-grid. Therefore I need to access the current row. I had something like this in mind but I don't know how to access the current row within columnDefs. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

```
columnDefs: [
    { name: "id", field: "id"},
    { name: "firends", field: "friends", editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', editDropdownOptionsArray: findFriendsForId(row.id)
]

var findFriendsForId = function(id) {
    // find friends and return them as array
}
```

Comment: I think what you need is ng-model="row.entity.id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out by myself. There is a function called
**editDropdownOptionsFunction**.

[Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/commit/480927ffdd6ae1e4951c149a925e2dae5e2352fc) is an example of it.